# "Security Err: Dom Exception" thrown when nesting ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Here's the issue.  I'm extracting gmail contacts through an ajax call in javascript/jquery like this:

```
function getUserInfo() {
  var xml_parse = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: SCOPE + '?max-results=9999&access_token=' + acToken
    data: null,
    success: function (resp) {
      xml_parse = $.parseXML(resp);
      callGmailHelperWebService(xml_parse);
    },
    dataType: "jsonp"
   });
 }

 function callGmailHelperWebService(xml_parse) {
   GmailHelperService.ConvertXMLToList(xml_parse, onSuccess, onFailed, null);
 }
```

So, as you can see, if the initial ajax call is successful, i call a function which calls a web service that sits on the save server as my project (in fact, it's part of the project).

My web service (GmailHelperService) is wired up correctly, as I can definitely call it in other places (like right after this ajax call, for example).  However, when I try to call it within the "success" portion of the ajax call, i get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

My theory is that this has something to do with cross-domain issues, but I can't understand why.  And I certainly can't figure out how to fix this.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Your `dataType` is `"jsonp"`, this means your data will become a JavaScript object within the success callback if it is valid. Why are you then parsing that as XML? How does that even make sense? It's a JavaScript object, not an XMLString...

Comment: Hi Kevin,  thanks for the response.  I had found this code somewhere buried in the google's documentation for implementing their Contacts API, so I didn't think to change it.  Regardless, the data it passes back (resp) is far from jsonp.  It's just a string representation of an xml document.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is a data transfer method that involves sending your data in this format:

```
callback({"foo":"bar"});
```

As you can see, this is NOT xml. It is JSON wrapped in a callback method that will get executed when the request is done loading, thus allowing it to be cross-domain because it can be requested using a `<script>` tag.

You cannot simply change your dataType to JSONP and return xml, expecting it to work. XML != JSONP. You can however return XML in jsonp, for example, `callback({"xml","... xml string here "})` but be mindful of quotes, all json keys and values must be wrapped in double quotes, inner-quotes need to be handled appropriately.

If your request is a same domain request (Same protocol, same subdomain, same domain, and same port,) then you can change your dataType to "XML" if you are returning XML. Otherwise, you need to either setup a proxy script to get the xml for you, or have your webservice return JSONP.

For example, the following urls are all considered cross-domain from each other.

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
http://example.com:8080
```

All of the above urls would be considered cross-domain, even if they are on the same server.

Comment: Okay, very interesting, and a bit confusing. Based on this answer, I'm not really sure how to adjust things to make it work.  I mean, say, in the code above, i never called "callGmailHelperWebService," and instead I just inputted the parse results into an array of objects (as I was doing), it works.  The only thing that does not work is the function call "callGmailHelperWebService," which kicks off my own web service.  So how do I apply what you're saying to my web service (which expects a string as a parameter, and gets one).

Comment: Is your webservice cross-domain?

Comment: No.  Regardless, my web service definitely works in my code.  After all, if I called "callGmailHelperWebService" outside of the $.ajax() (but within the same function "getUserInfo", it works.

Comment: Ah ok so this has nothing to do with the webservice then. Can you debug further to see exactly which line is throwing that error?

Comment: You're absolutely right, and as ashamed as I am to admit this, further debugging actually found the problem.  It turns out I was passing my web service the parsed string (that is, xml), when it was expecting a string.  

I can't believe I didn't see that.  Apologies, but thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem. You aren't the first one to solve your own problem, :p